# How to run Pentaho transformations in parallel and limit executors count

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

The task is to run defined number of transformations (.ktr) in parallel. 
Each transformation opens it's own database connection to read data.
But we have a limitation on given user, who has only 5 allowed parallel connection to DB and let's consider that this could not be changed. 
So when I start job depicted below, only 5 transformations finish their work successfully, and other 5 fails with db connection error.

[image]

I know that there is an option to redraw job scheme to have only 5 parallel sequences, but I don't like this approach, as it requires reimplementation when count of threads changes.

Is it possible to configure some kind of pool of executors, so Pentaho job will understand that even if there were 10 transformations provided, only random 5 could be processed in parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept is the following:

1. Catch database connection error during transformation run attempt
2. Wait a couple of seconds
3. Retry run of a transformation

Look at attached transformation picture. It works for me.

Disadvantages:

- A lot of connection errors in the logs, which could confuse.
- Given solution could turn in infinite loop (but could be amended to avoid it)

[image]

Comment: It can be amended by restricting the number of tries

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you know the number of parallel database connections available. If you know this, use switch/case component and then number of transformations in parallel.  Second option is to use job-executor.In Job Executor, if you can set variable which in turn call the job accordingly. For example, you are calling a job using job-executor with value
c:/data-integrator/parallel_job_${5}.kjb   where 5 is number of connections available
or
c:/data-integrator/parallel_job_${7}.kjb where 7 is number of connections available
 Is this making sense to you.

Comment: It is still unclear for me how to use a switch case in transformation to dynamically change threads count. Do you mean create cases for 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ... threads in ktr-file?

Comment: Yes. Do you have these many scenarios? I thought you might have 2 or 3 scenarios

Comment: We have another option. Play with database. If you know that job should run 5 transformations , rest should not run. For this, create one entry in database with job_id in every transformations and have a check inside if count for that job_id >5 , don't run the code inside it. Hence it will run all the transformations but code will be executed for 5 only.

Comment: So does it mean that I need to create new table with integer in database and increment value when new transformation starts and decrement when transformation finishes? And all transformations will check this value before start?

Comment: No, incremental that only once when your job runs , and start making entry with same  job_id in all transformations. if number of entries for that job_id > 5 , you code will not  get executed. For example job_id=1 for first then, there are 10 transformations. if number of entries for job_id=1 exceeds 5 . don't run main code  inside the transformation.

Comment: I think I found the best solution with your nudge. Let me check how it works and then I will share here.